# VSIX VS 22 не проходит InitializeAsync

Tags: c#

Я новичок в разработке расширений под VS
Пытаюсь сделать запись в отдельный файл всех изменений в редакторе кода.
Нашёл ивент, отвечающий за изменение строки, но по консоли видно, что ничего не происходит и похоже ивент даже не был зарегестрирован.
После этого я решил добавить вывод текста в консоль в InitializeAsync и ивент - ничего, ничего не выводит.
Тогда я решил вывод в коносль заменить на вывод в файл, так же - ничего, файл пустой.
Пытался дебагать - "Нет загруженных символов для этого документа", не фиксится.

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

namespace YoticVSIX
{
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
    [Guid("68329381-c591-4ded-8130-96f2a0cf553c")]
    public sealed class YoticVSIXPackage : AsyncPackage
    {
        DocumentEvents docE;
        Document doc;
        DTE dte;
        public void Connect()
        {
            dte = (DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));
            doc = dte.ActiveDocument;
            docE = dte.Events.DocumentEvents;
            dte.Events.TextEditorEvents.LineChanged += LineChanged;
        }
        public void LineChanged(TextPoint StartPoint, TextPoint EndPoint, int Hint)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\test.txt", $@"
StartPoint: Line: {StartPoint.Line}, CharOff: {StartPoint.LineCharOffset},
EndPoint: Line: {EndPoint.Line}, CharOff: {EndPoint.LineCharOffset},
Рандомная хуйня:{Hint}.
");
        }
        protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\test.txt", "qqq");
Console.WriteLine("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            Connect();
            await this.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется, студия лениво грузит расширения, то есть только при необходимости, например при обращении к элементам интерфейса расширения или вызове команд, связанных с ним.

Comment: @aepot, хорошо, я попробую сделать окно и кнопку для расширения

Answer (score 0):

Ответ кроется в том, что метод будет вызван только при ипользовании расширения, я сменил проект на VSIX Command Community и теперь при нажатии на мою команду расширение начинает работу. Не знаю что ещё может побудить его стартануть, буду рад увидеть комментарии или дополнение.
`Я также нашёл метод dte.ExecuteCommand, возможно его как-нибудь возможно будет использовать`

Comment: легко же https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/loading-vspackages, читать доки полезно ) `[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)]`

Comment: я 2 часа смотрел крутого мужичка из работников microsoft, он за это время создал окно и кнопку...

Comment: У меня теперь новая проблема, ивенты сами по себе отписываются, исключений нет...

Comment: https://prnt.sc/t7efa6pvtKSY